# Update fields on reverse M2M relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

Having two models:

```py
class Publication(model.Models):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Article(model.Models):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, related_name='articles') 

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want that, when I add a `Publication` to an `Article`, the `updated_at` field of `Publication` also gets updated:

```py
a1 = Article.objects.create(name='Article 1')
p1 = Publication.objects.create(name='Publication 1')

a1.publications.add(p1)
print(a1.updated_at)
# Will print the timestamp when I added p1 to a1.

print(p1.updated_at)
# Will print the timestamp when I **created** p1. I want to print the time when it was added to a1.
```

I know I can do this using **signals** but I was wondering if there's an easier way, as think that signals add extra complexity to the code.

Comment: Have you tried: `p1 = Publication.objects.create(name='Publication, updated_at=a1.updated_at)`

Comment: Yes but these operations happen from many sides: admin, API, workers... I was looking for a solution that applies to everything.

Comment: It might be worth creating a custom through table for this